# Select dropdown box is flickering on mac chrome browser

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome, select, flicker

I have a wordpress site and one of the pages has got the form with select box. The select dropbox works fine on PC browsers and even on mac safari. The only issue is on mac chrome. When I hover on the select box to select the option and do nothing the option lists is glitchy and flickering. I haven't used any kind of css or jquery plugin for select box, just the normal css has been used.

I googled but didn't find anyone having such issue or may be I couldn't type the proper keyword while searching. Can anyone provide an idea how can this be fixed.

Thank you the help.

Comment: Thank you so much @AndyHoffman for the comment. I have implemented this on staging, its not live yet. I am sorry that I can't provide the staging link. Let me know you one thing that, the site is using foundation framework. Thanks

Comment: Any update on this issue?